# Not getting HTML using curl, why?

Tags: php, curl

Why am I not getting the HTML code when I use PHP curl? This is my code:

```
// $content = file_get_contents('http://www.datadiary.com/Company/311734/dimsinstituteofhotelmanagement');

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.datadiary.com/Company/311734/dimsinstituteofhotelmanagement');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, false);

$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $content;
```

Answer (score 3):

By default `curl_exec` sends the response to the output (usually the browser). Set the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option if you want `curl_exec` to return the result instead:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

Relevant manual entries:

- http://php.net/curl-exec
- http://php.net/curl-setopt

Comment: After setting this option i can not get content

Comment: It works for me, do you have the cURL extension installed? Also, the resource in question is returning a `500 Internal Server Error` for me

Comment: yes it returning a 500 Internal Server Error . but  this url can be open in brouser.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the option to return the transfer as a string:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

Comment: After setting this option i can not get content